# python 2.6: socket.error (fixing Trac)

Tags: python, exception, trac

I'm trying to fix the following exception I get while running Trac 0.11 with mod_fcgid on Apache2:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Connection.run of <trac.web._fcgi.Connection object at 0x88b5fec>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/trac/web/_fcgi.py", line 661, in run
    except socket.error, e:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

I modified the relevant block in _fcgi.py to lock like this:

```
def run(self):
    """Begin processing data from the socket."""
    self._keepGoing = True
    while self._keepGoing:
        try:
            self.process_input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        except socket.error, e:
            if e[0] == errno.EBADF:
                break
            raise
        except select.error, e:
            if e[0] == errno.EBADF: # Socket was closed by Request.
                break
            raise

    self._cleanupSocket()
```

The line causing the exception is `except socket.error, e:`. Reading the Pydocs I see 'socket' is a class and there should be a member named 'error', so why this exception?

I'm usually coding C or Java and never did something in Python, can someone enlighten me? :)

Thanks,

lynix

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you don't have a `socket` variable that has a value of `None`? This sample:

```
import socket
socket = None
print socket.error
```

produces exactly the same error. As a quick hack, you can try to add `import socket as socketLib` at the beginning of your file and replacing your line with `except socketLib.error, e`... but just to identify the problem!

Comment: I did as you say, changing the import to 'socketLib'. The error now occurs with socketLib:

    except socketLib.error, e:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'